# Creating separate data source for my session spring using JDBC and spring data jpa in spring boot

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2, spring-session

I am a newbie in spring-boot and i want to configure my spring session with jdbc using h2 database, but it does not create a database and table in my h2 embedded database, it creates it in the PostgreSQL, using the PostgreSQL data source i configured in my applications properties file. How do i make my spring app use my embedded h2 db for storing sessions only while not conflicting with the PostgreSQL data source for my JPA

https://github.com/eshiett1995/SessionProject. i would love if someone could help me with the session

Comment: Can you paste the code or share a github URL to the project? Without code it is pretty hard to find applicable solution.

Comment: @DevDio will do

Comment: @DevDio done it https://github.com/eshiett1995/SessionProject

Answer (score 1):

check https://github.com/nomanbplmp/CustomSessionStoreExample  to see complete example.

In order to make session store work with other than primary database it is required to provide custom session repository and override spring's internal as given below.

```
@Configuration
@EnableJdbcHttpSession
class SessionConfig { 
    @Bean
    public JdbcOperationsSessionRepository sessionRepository(){
      DataSource ds =   DataSourceBuilder.create().driverClassName("org.h2.Driver").username("sa").url("jdbc:h2:file:~/test").build();
     return   new SessionRepo(ds,new DataSourceTransactionManager(ds));

    }
}


class SessionRepo extends JdbcOperationsSessionRepository  {

    public SessionRepo(DataSource dataSource, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
        super(dataSource, transactionManager);

    }


}
```

Comment: it doesnt work, with @Primary, it just creates a table for my entities in h2db alone

Comment: it didnt work as i wanted. it created the session tables in the h2 database as i wanted, but instead of creating my entities in PostgreSQL,  it created them in h2 also.