# Spring Session with JDBC - How to Use a Separate DB as a Session Store

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-session

I am working on an application that uses Spring Session JDBC. I also am using Spring JPA for other entities. My question is, how does one configure a Spring Boot application to allow for a separate database to be used for Session storage?

I have referenced this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45769603/creating-separate-data-source-for-my-session-spring-using-jdbc-and-spring-data-j), but it appears the JdbcHttpSessionConfiguration constructor noted in the answer is no longer valid (I am using Spring Boot 2.1.1). Other than that, I was unable to find any documentation on the subject. I found information on how to configure Spring Session with a JDBC backing, and how to use multiple data sources in Spring, but not how to combine the two. I reckon it might involves extending `JdbcHttpSessionConfiguration`, but unfortunately, I am not able to figure out how to properly do so.

This is all I have thus far:

```
    @Configuration
class SessionConfig extends JdbcHttpSessionConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2).build();
    }

}
```

However, the above attempts to create all my entity tables in the H2 store as well.

My primary datasource (PostgreSQL) is specified in my `application.properties`.

```
spring.session.store-type=jdbc
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/auth
spring.datasource.username=xxx
spring.datasource.password=xxx
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since Spring Boot 2.0.0 you can specify the `DataSource` that Spring Session should use by using annotation `@SpringSessionDataSource`.

> Qualifier annotation for a DataSource to be injected in
>   JdbcOperationsSessionRepository.

The method inside the Spring `JdbcHttpSessionConfiguration` class that sets the desired datasource.

```
@Autowired
public void setDataSource(@SpringSessionDataSource ObjectProvider<DataSource> springSessionDataSource, ObjectProvider<DataSource> dataSource)
```

To achieve the desired result one has to configure a secondary datasource for use in Spring Session and annotate the bean with `@SpringSessionDataSource`. Below is the configuration that worked for me.

application.properties

```
session.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/session
session.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
session.datasource.username=postgres
session.datasource.password=thepassword

primary.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
primary.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
primary.datasource.username=postgres
primary.datasource.password=thepassword
```

The database config

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DatabaseConfig {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("primary.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties primaryDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
        return primaryDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder()
                .type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("session.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties sessionDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    @SpringSessionDataSource
    public DataSource springSessionDataSource() {
        return sessionDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder()
                .type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    }
}
```

Remember to run the `org/springframework/session/jdbc/schema-thedbplatform.sql` schema file on your db if you're not using a embedded database. In my case I ran `org/springframework/session/jdbc/schema-postgresql.sql`.

If you want to use a H2 database for you session management you can remove the `session.datasource...` from your `application.properties` and configure your datasources as follows.

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DatabaseConfig {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("primary.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties primaryDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
        return primaryDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder()
                .type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    }

    @Bean
    @SpringSessionDataSource
    public EmbeddedDatabase springSessionDataSource() {
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
                .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
                .addScript("org/springframework/session/jdbc/schema-h2.sql").build();
    }
}
```